# Vector equation of line containing point and perpendicular to plane

Tags: algebra-precalculus, vectors, 3d, vector-analysis

How would one find the vector equation of the line that contains the point (x0, y0, z0) and is perpendicular to the plane Ax + By + Cz = D?

Comment: Hint: what is a perpendicular vector to the given plane?

Comment: Yes indeed, it is worth looking into that link.